# CodeIgniter doesn't load views as expected

Tags: codeigniter, view

I deployed an app and I've got a problem. This is my controller:

```
class Account extends CI_Controller {
  function test() {
    echo "hello";
    $this->load->view('account/test');
    echo "hello again";
  }
```

The output shows `hellohelloagain`.

The `load->view()` method is not called. This happens in all controllers.
The problem doesn't exist in development environment.

I have already:

- Removed hooks
- Checked permissions

There are no warnings or errors in my Apache logs.

**UPDATE**

I just discovered something weird:

```
function index() {
    $this->load->view('welcome/index'); // NOTHING

    $output = $this->load->view('welcome/index', array(), true);
    echo $output; // WORKS FINE
}
```

Comment: Can you replace the echo commands with $this->output->append_output("hello");

Comment: Try to add ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1); to the top of this file, maybe there's an error.

Comment: CodeGodie, there are no errors in the output.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Account extends CI_Controller 
{
  function test() {
    echo "hello";// No 01
    $this->load->view('account/test'); //No 02
    echo "hello again"; //No 03
 }
```

in **No 01** it will show `hello` word as you mentioned. And again you loading a view in **No 02**(this view is blank page, other wise you get error page not found).

Error is :

> An Error Was Encountered
>
> Unable to load the requested file: account/test.php

So your **test view** is empty page. then in **No 03** your are passing `hello again`. so this will also appear in your view.

so your final output come as `hellohello again`.

**So Finely it means** your code is working perfectly and well.

**To test** your view whether working or not

In your view(test.php) write this line and see the output

```
<h1>Hi, I'm here</h1>
```

read this for further Knowledge

1. [Views](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)
2. [Controllers](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html)
3. [Models](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html)

Comment: The file `account/test.php` exists but it is not rendered. I double checked the permissions.

I disabled optional layout's hook and the error still happens. I saw the documentation but the issue doesn't appear in any apache log.

Comment: The file doesn't load. I created a welcome controller. It should render welcome/index.php. The file views/welcome/index.php exists but the content of this file doesn't load

Comment: if my answer helpful grateful by accepting it or Vote it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

have you try to create separate view for each echo like this?

```
    class Account extends CI_Controller {
        function test() {
            $this->load->view('account/hello');
            $this->load->view('account/test');
            $this->load->view('account/hello-again');
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you explain why @Abdulla ?

Comment: in his code he just use `echo "hello";` so this is not view. so how you will tell  `$this->load->view('account/hello');`

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

I commited a mistake in my hook configuration:

```
 $hook['display_override'][] = array('class' => 'layout', 'function' => 'show_layout', 'filename' => 'layout.php', 'filepath' => 'hooks');
```

Actually, the real name is Layout.php, while the configuration required layout.php.

Thanks everybody